# The intersection of $X = \{x ∈ \Bbb R\ |\ 0 ≤ x < 6 \}$ and $Y=\{x∈\Bbb Z\ |\ −π≤x≤7\}$ is

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The intersection of $\ X = \{x ∈ \Bbb R\ |\ 0 ≤ x < 6 \}$ and $Y=\{x∈\Bbb Z\ |\ −π≤x≤7\}$
is $$\{x ∈\Bbb Z\ |\ 0 ≤ x < 6 \}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: That is correct assuming that $Z$ and $\Bbb Z$ mean the same thing to you, you have mixed notation appearing in your post.

Comment: @JMoravitz oh yes, that is the same thing.

Comment: Yes,that is correct.